# Loopback GroupBy and Sum Queries on MySQL Datasource

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

In Loopback 3.0, I have a model `'Hotel'` connected to my mysqld DB which has properties `"availableBedCount"` (e.g. 11) and `"city"` (e.g. "New York").

I want to query this model to get the sum of the `availableBedCounts`, grouped by `city` but I cannot find any functionality built into loopback that would facilitate this - is that correct?

The only ways to achieve this appear to be:

- Use a remote method to query all data and perform the sum/group by logic in the method. I don't believe this will scale with a large data set.
- Execute custom SQL. According to the docs "This feature has not been fully tested and is not officially supported".

**What is the best option for performing my sum/groupBy query?**

If executing custom SQL, do I need to create a new model specifically to model the aggregated data (e.g. an object with an `'availableBedCountSum'` property and a `'city'` property)?